# Use %userprofile% in android build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I would like to use the equivilant of %userprofile% in my build.gradle file to specify the buildDir path. I have already unsuccessfully tried **%userprofile%, System.getenv('HOME') and $System.env.HOME** amoung which both last ones simply returned "null"

Is there at all a way to get the %userprofile% path in the build.gradle file?

Comment: Are you sure you have an environment variable named 'HOME'? Because I think the `System.getenv('HOME')` should work. Print all the env variables by using `System.getenv()` and see if there is a HOME variable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me:

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```